# Redirecting stdout and stderr to a single file in c++

Tags: c++, file-io, stdout

How to redirect stdout and stderr to a single file in c++?

what i tried was:

```
if((LogStream = freopen(strFilePath.c_str(), "w", stdout)) == NULL)
{
    cout << "Failed to redirect console logs\n";
}
if((LogStream = freopen(strFilePath.c_str(), "a", stderr)) == NULL)
{
    cout << "Failed to redirect console logs\n";
}
```

But it is not working as i expected.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could redirect it when you run it with `>> file.log 2>&1`

Comment: "not working as i expected". No useful information here. What are you observing? What do you expect to observe?

Comment: What is not working as expected.
`"Failed to redirect console logs\n";` will be only printed if it fails to open file.

Try adding line after if block to check whether file is properly opened.

Comment: operating system may not allow you to open a file twice for writing concurrently. If it does... I wouldn't expect magic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you can change each of the raw file/C buffered file/C++ buffered streams:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  // unbuffered system-call level write() access:
  ::fclose(stderr);
  if (::dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, STDERR_FILENO) == -1) {
    cout << "dup2() failed!" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  char msg_err[] = "write(STDERR_FILENO) OK.\n";
  char msg_out[] = "write(STDOUT_FILENO) still OK.\n";
  write(STDERR_FILENO, msg_err, strlen(msg_err));
  write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg_out, strlen(msg_out));

  // buffered C-style access: (ordering may be weird w/o fflush())
  stderr = ::fdopen(STDOUT_FILENO, "a");
  fprintf(stderr, "fprintf(stderr) OK.\n");
  fprintf(stdout, "fprintf(stdout) still OK.\n");

  // buffered C++ access:
  std::cerr.rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf());
  cerr << "cerr << OK.\n";
  cout << "cout << still OK.\n";
}
```

That said, it's still better to do this from the invoking shell.